# Python: how to capture Ctrl-O key press in QT GUI?

Tags: python, qt

In a PyQt 4 app, how can I set pressing Ctrl-O to trigger my file-open routine?

I have already set up an `eventFilter()` to handle keypresses from my widgets in the GUI. I can't get the filter to respond to Ctrl-O.

Ideally, I'd like a solution that will work globally across the GUI regardless of which widget the user is currently interacting with. Is is possible to connect the eventFilter to the entire app itself, not just individual widgets?

(Note: above, I've typed "Ctrl-O" using the uppercase O for clarity. In reality, the user will likely press "Ctrl-o".

I'm using PyQt4, Python 3.5, on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Have you look at `QShortcut`?

Comment: Excellent!  I had no idea about QShortcut. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to @ilotXXI for the pointer to QShortcut.

Here's the code that worked for me. I added it to the `def __init__(self):` routine of my MainWindow class. `ChooseFiles` is my file-open routine defined elsewhere in the class.

```
self.connect(QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QKeySequence("Ctrl+o")), self), QtCore.SIGNAL('activated()'), self.ChooseFiles)
```